Did the Enlightenment "think of art primarily as self-expression"?
In Finding the Raga, Amit Chaudhuri argues that raga music is modernist in that it is non-representational: a raga does not depict anything other than itself. He supports this claim by drawing on the history of aesthetics, Indian as well as Western. Discussing the absence of vibrato in raga performance, he writes:

The Indian classical musical traditions are non-humanistic, in that their focus is not personality or psychology, but sur and taal, pitch and temporality. Vibrato adds emotion; but the note alone is joyous and equanimous, and makes the artist (and vibrato) redundant. The belief in the proximity of calm to joy goes back, in India, at the very least to the tenth-century philosopher Abhinavagupta, who was also a theorist of rasa, or aesthetic 'juice' or 'savouring'. There are nine rasas, and, for Abhinavagupta, the one underlying them all—the 'shant' or 'tranquil' rasa—is coeval with 'ananda', 'joy'. This is to point to a lineage also for a great deal in nineteenth- and twentieth-century Western art that constitutes a silent rebellion against the Enlightenment's human-centered universe and its tendency to think of art primarily as self-expression. Take Wordsworth's curious remark that poetry is 'emotion recollected in tranquillity'. How can emotion, felt or remembered, be tranquil, unless by 'recollection' Wordsworth means self-extinction?
Chaudhuri, Amit. Finding the Raga: an Improvisation on Indian Music. New York: NYRB, 2021. pp. 229–230

Chaudhuri's range of reference is indeed impressive. In making the case that post-Enlightenment art moves away from a focus on the individual personality, he draws upon everyone from Kant to Arnold to Eliot. Yet I find his arguments difficult to accept, particularly his claim about "the Enlightenment's human-centered universe." On the one hand, the works of Swift, Dryden, Johnson, Molière, Racine, and other writers of the period between the Baroque era and Romanticism do not strike me "primarily as self-expression." On the other, the claim that Wordsworth was not chiefly about expressing himself but about "self-extinction" boggles my mind.
Is Chaudhuri drawing upon currently accepted understandings of literary and intellectual history in arguing that Enlightenment art is primarily self-expression and that the Romantics sought the extinction of personality, or is he an outlier? If his views are indeed nonstandard (as they seem to me to be), is he drawing on some alternative but recognized scholarly tradition that counters the received wisdom regarding post-Enlightenment literature? Or is he making these claims out of whole cloth?

This is the same Amit Chaudhur who "was Professor of Contemporary Literature at the University of East Anglia from 2006 to 2021". I'm confused.

@Tsundoku Personally I think he's the confused one. And to be fair, he is a fine novelist, and the Enlightenment is not precisely "contemporary." But he does have an Oxford DPhil in English, so ....
